# Finding a word in a set of characters PHP

Tags: php, string, find, cpu-word, strpos

I'm looking for a way to find out if a word is somewhere in a set of characters. For example if the word "looking" is in "hereisthewordim*looking*for"

```
if( strpos("looking", "hereisthewordimlookingfor")  !== false) {
 echo "true";
}
```

Comment: You can use exactly what you have.  What's the question?

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the parameters:

```
strpos("hereisthewordimlookingfor", "looking")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this:

```
if(stristr("hereisthewordimlookingfor","looking")) {
    echo "true";
};
```